# Adding Custom Domain to Azure CDN Endpoint Caused Downtime to CDN

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-cdn

When we tried to add a custom domain to our current Azure CDN endpoint, the CDN was down while it was trying to verify and issue an SSL certificate for the custom domain. I cancelled the process and everything came back after a few minutes.

I know that in the instructions it states to map the custom domain to the temporary cdnverify subdomain,https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-map-content-to-custom-domain#map-the-temporary-cdnverify-subdomain, but I think this is only if the URL we are using for the custom domain is in use. Is this correct?

Is there any way to avoid this downtime or should this not happen?

Answer (score 0):

> but I think this is only if the URL we are using for the custom domain
>   is in use. Is this correct?

Correct. The [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-map-content-to-custom-domain#map-the-temporary-cdnverify-subdomain) states that when you map an existing domain that is in production.  First map your custom domain to your CDN endpoint hostname with the Azure cdnverify subdomain to create a temporary CNAME mapping. so you can access your custom domain URL without interruption while the DNS mapping occurs.

> Is there any way to avoid this downtime or should this not happen?

If you have verified that the cdnverify subdomain has been successfully mapped to your endpoint, you can then [map the custom domain directly to your CDN endpoint hostname](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-map-content-to-custom-domain#map-the-permanent-custom-domain). After creating CNAME for your custom domain, you can delete the temporary cdnverify subdomain CNAME record. It should avoid this downtime.

Comment: @nancy-xiong-msft But if we are pointing to the non-custom domain of the CDN like somedomain.azureedge.net, will there be an interruption to that domain while we add a custom one?

Comment: If you have a custom domain like `contoso.com`, and an endpoint hostname `domain1.azureedge.net` which is created at the first time you enable the CDN endpoint. You have to create CNAME for `cdn.contoso.com` point to `domain1.azureedge.net` to finish the CDN custom domain mapping. If you have another endpoint like `somedomain.azureedge.net`, You can use another CNAME like `www.contoso.com` point to `somedomain.azureedge.net`.

Comment: Refer to [Create a CNAME DNS record](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-map-content-to-custom-domain#create-a-cname-dns-record). `you can use different subdomains from the same custom domain for different Azure service endpoints by using multiple CNAME records. You can also map a custom domain with different subdomains to the same CDN endpoint.`